# Awake application without using VoIP when user killed iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, voip, callkit

I am trying to develop whatsApp like calling feature in an application of mine.
For audio call, I am using VoIP to initialize the CallKit and it's working perfectly.

But I am not able to get Video call work just like whatsApp.

If I assume that whatsApp is delivering is VoIP and then showing local notification. But as per iOS 13 documentation, you have to report incoming call to CallKit if you are using VoIP.

And If I think of sending silent notification, it won't work if user killed the application manually.

I have thought of many solutions but none behaves like whatsApp does.

Can anyone help me with this? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit

Answer (score 0):

You can just use normal push notifications, they will always be delevered. Your server has to generate a push every n-seconds that tells the user that he has an incoming video call.

Comment: But it will result into stack of same notifications in notification center

Comment: I was about to tell you to implement a Notification Service Extension to remove previous notifications, but then I stumbled upon this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597777/how-to-delete-delivered-notifications-from-notification-service-extension that seems to state that it isn't possible.

Comment: In the meanwhile, in trying to understand what WhatsApp really does, I've found out a strange thing. I've set the "Show Previews" in iOS settings to "When Unlocked", so that when the phone is locked I shouldn't be able to read the content of any notification. But strangely enough, when I receive a WhatsApp video call, the content of the notification is visible: "Incoming video call...". I cannot understand how it is possible...